# "broom her fast" meaning

Tags: idioms, figurative-language

What does "*broom her*" mean? Ive encountered to this quite peculiar term while watching spider man series. This expression takes place in the dialogue between norman osborn and his son harry.
It goes like that:

N-**Your mother was beautiful too, they are(referring to women) all beautiful until they are snarling after your trust fund like a pack of ravening wolves.*

H-*You don't know about her dad.*

N- ... *[do what you need with her and broom her fast.](https://youtu.be/PUgAXj3W0rc)**

I know what broom does mean and refer to, in this case it is probably used to mean "dump her, break up with her" but is it actually viable to use broom? I checked it out on the web and didnt manage to find its verb term and saw some people's comments saying like this is never used in american english but only british english etc etc. To be honest, it sounds weird to one's ear. Id never use it in daily speech.

Comment: Hope this helps, I suppose.
http://broom.urbanup.com/8954

Answer (score 0):

Not a common idiom, apparently it means sweep her away. In his metaphor, he is saying you should treat women like dirt. So we know he is a "bad guy".

But it also connects to the "spider" theme, since you might use a broom to get rid of a spider in your house.

I've done a bit of a search, and I can't find any use of the word "broom" in this context except connected to this line in this movie. So I assume it was a piece of dialogue created by the authors to show what a bad person he is. It is not used in British English.